# disabling ssl with mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, ssl, mysql2

I am using the mysql2 gem in a Sinatra app, and when I try to connect, I get the error:

```
SSL connection error: socket layer receive error
```

If I use the mysql command-line client, I get the same error, unless I use the --skip-ssl option.  This is the command that works with the --skip-ssl arg, and fails without it with the above error:

```
mysql --host=localhost  --user=root --password=root  --port=3306 -p --protocol=tcp --skip-ssl
```

Is there similar 'skip-ssl' option I can add to my establish_connection() method

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql2",
  :host     => "127.0.0.1",
  :username => "root",
  :password => "root",
  :database => "db",
  :port => 3306,
  :protocol => "tcp"
)
```

to disable ssl in the gem?

Comment: are you sure the error is coming from mysql? have u tried rails console? is this a ruby or rails app?

Comment: It is a Sinatra app. The error is word-for-word the same as the error the mysql command line utility returns. Thats why I want to know how to pass 'skip-ssl=true' through to the gem's config.

Comment: Do you happen to have a config file that sets one of the ssl-* values for the client side? Also, which mysql server version are you using? the SSL connection semantics look changed between pre-5.7 and 5.7

Comment: @Kashyap I have modified my question to show the command line that works.  I do not have a config file, and I'm sure thats part of my problem.

Comment: did you find how to do this? I have the same issue with a rails app

Comment: IIRC I had to just use another (older) mysql version, maybe some sort of client/server/gem incompatibility.